# (C++) SQRT function only outputs four decimal places

Tags: c++, double, precision, sqrt, long-double

I'm trying to find the square root of a number through this function and it's not very precise. For example, if you enter 496, my output is 22.2711, while my professor's sample output is 22.271057.

I've tried making  an int, double, and long double and the answer stays the same.

I can't use setprecision() either because this code must work for any number, so if the square root is 2 then it needs to print as "2" rather than "2.000000".

Here is the function responsible for finding the square root:

```
long double myInt::squareRoot() {
    long double value = 0.0;
    value = sqrtl(static_cast<long double>(num));

    return value;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

example:

```
#include <cmath>
int main {
int number = 496;
long double result = 0.0;
result = sqrtl(static_cast<long double>(number));
cout << result;
```

output here is 22.2711.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see the actual result?

Comment: If you want more digits you'll have to use `setprecision` at some point. You could format the number into a string and trim trailing zeroes if you need to before printing it.

Comment: How are you examining the value? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Your title is inaccurate. `sqrtl()` doesn't *output* anything. It returns a value of type `long double`, and in your example that value should be accurate to about 19 or 20 decimal places. Your problem is in how the value is displayed, not how it's computed. Also, have you tried looking at the output of `std::cout << std::setprecision(42) << 2.0L << "\n"`?

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! What is 2.0L / what does it do? I tried setprecision(6) and it displayed as 4 decimal places, so "2.0L" must be the important part.

Comment: @Sunny It's a long double literal.

Comment: `std::cout << std::setprecision(42) << 2.0L << "\n"` should print just "2" (it does on my system). Did you try that exact expression? You were concerned that you can't use `std::setprecision` because you want `2.0` to be printed as `2`, not `2.0000`.